# How to determine Controller name and Action name in IResourceFilter?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am writing an ASP.NET Core resource filter and I want to disable handling for some controller/actions in OnResourceExecuting method.

I can't find any api to get controller name and action name in [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.ResourceExecutingContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.filters.resourceexecutingcontext?view=aspnetcore-2.1) class.

Anyone has any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `ResourceExecutingContext` contains an `ActionDescriptor` property ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.abstractions.actiondescriptor?view=aspnetcore-2.1)).

This is the base class of either `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerActionDescriptor` or `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.PageActionDescriptor`.

So when you cast it to `ControllerActionDescriptor` ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllers.controlleractiondescriptor?view=aspnetcore-2.1)), you can access the `ControllerName` and `ActionName` properties.

```
if(resourceContext.ActionDescriptor is ControllerActionDescriptor controllerDescriptor)
{
    var controllerName = controllerDescriptor.ControllerName;
}
```

Comment: Voted. I will test it later and mark it as approved after test. It seems correct solution. Thank you!

Comment: How does one access the ResourceExecutingContext? It does not appear to be a static object.

Comment: @ChaimEliyah: Its a parameter passed to the resource filters `OnResourceExecuting`/`OnResourceExecuted` method, like in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-2.1#cancellation-and-short-circuiting

Comment: Great. I was able to get at it through `Context.Request.HttpContext.GetRouteData().Values["controller"].ToString()` ...but I haven't tested.